# Using 'vain' in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition follows 'vain' when it is used as a synonym for proud?

Example:

> The actress was vain ___ her looks.

It should be worth noting that I'm in ICSE, and that at this point, I don't even know if the sentence is correct at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *about* in that sentence so it reads: 
*The actress was vain about her looks* , which makes complete sense as an English sentence

Just keep in mind that *vain* isn't perfectly synonymous with *proud*, as vain in that sense means to be excessively proud of or concerned about one's own appearance.

Source: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vain?s=t

Comment: Another suggestion: "The actress was vain regarding her looks."

Comment: I too feel that regarding would be more appropriate. +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the sentence isn't quite right. My argument would be that *to be vain* is a state of mind, it's not an action done towards an object.

You could say "The actress was vain".

Vain means: *having or showing an excessively high opinion of one's appearance* - so to mention something about looks is redundant, since the word *vain* already refers to that.

Comment: When an action is done towards an object, that's called a "direct object". When an action *involves* an object, that's an "indirect object". Indirect objects are separated from the verb by a preposition. The preposition "about" marks "her looks" as an indirect object; "her looks" descries the subject matter of her vanity.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that to mention "her looks" is redundant since vanity is already about one's looks..- *to be vain* describes that already.

Comment: Your first paragraph talks about being vain not having a direct object (which is a bit weird, since "vain" is an adjective, and verbs, not adjectives, have objects). "Vain" absolutely is not restricted to looks.